# Can not compile fasm file

Tags: assembly, fasm

I'm trying to compile asm-xml. But I'm getting the following error:

```
error: illegal instruction.
```

The affected line is:

```
section '.asmdata' writeable
```

Anyone could help me to fix this iisue?

Thank you in advance,

Greetings
F

Comment: This sounds like it's context-related. Please post a (small) complete example.

Comment: Thank  you for feedback. Jens answered before I was able to get a feedback to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're compiling the wrong file. You should be compiling the assembly file that corresponds to your platform, **elf.asm** or **win32.asm**. *asm-xml.asm* is not in itself a complete assembly program.